# Python streamlit: Updated cells jump to default using streamlit

Tags: python, ag-grid, streamlit

I try to find a solution for the following issue.
I would like to upload an excel sheet, consisting of multiple sheets (use case here 2). Afterwards I added tabs via Streamlit and used the aggrid component to be able to change some cells. However if I change cells in Sheet 1 and jump to tab 2 and back, changes are gone. This is not the desired output, meaning that any changes done in the cell should remain.
I tried via st.cache and st.experimental_memo however without success.

My code is below

```
import numpy as np
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
from st_aggrid import GridOptionsBuilder, AgGrid, GridUpdateMode, DataReturnMode, JsCode,GridOptionsBuilder


excelfile=st.sidebar.file_uploader("Select Excel-File for cleansing",key="Raw_Data")



if excelfile==None:
    st.balloons()
    



tab1, tab2 = st.tabs(["Sheet 1", "Sheet 2"])



@st.cache()
def load_sheet1():
    sheet1=pd.read_excel(excelfile,sheet_name="Sheet1")
    return sheet1

@st.cache()
def load_sheet2():
    sheet1=pd.read_excel(excelfile,sheet_name="Sheet2")
    return sheet1


df=load_sheet1()
with tab1:
    gd = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(df)
    gd.configure_pagination(enabled=True)
    gd.configure_default_column(editable=True, groupable=True)
    gd.configure_selection(selection_mode="multiple", use_checkbox=True)
    gridoptions = gd.build()
    grid_table = AgGrid(
        df,
        gridOptions=gridoptions,
        update_mode=GridUpdateMode.SELECTION_CHANGED,
        theme="material",
    )



df1=load_sheet2()
with tab2:
    gd = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(df1)
    gd.configure_pagination(enabled=True)
    gd.configure_default_column(editable=True, groupable=True)
    gd.configure_selection(selection_mode="multiple", use_checkbox=True)
    gridoptions = gd.build()
    grid_table = AgGrid(
        df1,
        gridOptions=gridoptions,
        update_mode=GridUpdateMode.SELECTION_CHANGED,
        theme="material",
    )
```

I also can share with you my test excel file:

Sheet 1

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | C |
| B | D |

Sheet 2

| Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- |
| E | G |
| F | H |

Any kind of support how to eliminate this issue would be more than awesome

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Here is a solution without the load button.

I couldn't find a way to do it without adding a button to reload the page to apply changes. Since streamlit reruns the whole code every time you interact with it is a bit tricky to rendre elements the right way. Here is your code refactored. Hope this helps !

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
from st_aggrid import AgGrid, GridUpdateMode, GridOptionsBuilder

# Use session_state to keep stack of changes
if 'df' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.df = pd.DataFrame()
if 'df1' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.df1 = pd.DataFrame()
if 'excelfile' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.excelfile = None


@st.cache()
def load_sheet1():
    sheet1 = pd.read_excel(excelfile, sheet_name="Sheet1")
    return sheet1


@st.cache()
def load_sheet2():
    sheet1 = pd.read_excel(excelfile, sheet_name="Sheet2")
    return sheet1


def show_table(data):
    if not data.empty:
        gd = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(data)
        gd.configure_pagination(enabled=True)
        gd.configure_default_column(editable=True, groupable=True)
        gd.configure_selection(selection_mode="multiple", use_checkbox=True)
        gridoptions = gd.build()
        grid_table = AgGrid(
            data,
            gridOptions=gridoptions,
            # Use MODEL_CHANGED instead of SELECTION_CHANGED
            update_mode=GridUpdateMode.MODEL_CHANGED,
            theme="material"
        )
        # Get the edited table when you make changes and return it
        edited_df = grid_table['data']
        return edited_df
    else:
        return pd.DataFrame()


excelfile = st.sidebar.file_uploader("Select Excel-File for cleansing", key="Raw_Data")

if st.session_state.excelfile != excelfile:
    st.session_state.excelfile = excelfile
    try:
        st.session_state.df = load_sheet1()
        st.session_state.df1 = load_sheet2()
    except:
        st.session_state.df = pd.DataFrame()
        st.session_state.df1 = pd.DataFrame()

tab1, tab2 = st.tabs(["Sheet 1", "Sheet 2"])

with tab1:
    # Get the edited DataFrame from the ag grid object
    df = show_table(st.session_state.df)

with tab2:
    # Same thing here...
    df1 = show_table(st.session_state.df1)

# Then you need to click on a button to make the apply changes and
# reload the page before you go to the next tab
if st.button('Apply changes'):
    # Store new edited DataFrames in session state
    st.session_state.df = df
    st.session_state.df1 = df1
    # Rerun the page so that changes apply and new DataFrames are rendered
    st.experimental_rerun()
```

After loading your file and making your changes in the first tab hit the "apply changes" button to reload the page before moving to the second tab.

Comment: thanks so much my friend. Not possible to avoid the refresh and load button in order to make it more user friendly?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to get rid of the **apply changes** button. You can replace `df` and `df1` with `st.session_state.df` and `st.session_state.df1` in the 62nd and 66th lines (where you call `show_table()`) but you will see that the changes won't apply immediately until you interact a seconde time with the page to rerun the code.